# undefined index HTTP_HOST error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, server

I don't know what I did. As long as I remember, I never touched any http host configurations. Suddenly, my code-igniter application is not working.
I have 2 points of view, front end and back end.

The system front end works perfectly fine, but I cannot access the system in back end.

[image]

I checked my php_error_log file, and I got this message :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in D:\Xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

I opened htdocs/index.php , this is the file :
[image]

I don't know what to do, please help me. :(

Comment: Is your Xampp server is running mode..

Comment: http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/codeigniter-admin-panel
kindly follow this steps to create admin panel

Comment: You are redirecting too much, may be check code for redirect when session not exists

Comment: why are you doing this in htdocs/index.php ?

Comment: Why are not doing for selected project

Comment: @Rijin what do you mean?